# Why is memory management important?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I know this is a really dumb question but I feel I have been going about learning C++ wrong, ignoring memory too much. I always hear about memory management in C++ and C but what is it's importance to something like a video game, or some office program?

Comment: Because it is not infinite and if you don't manage it you will waste all of it.

Comment: It is like money management - a limited resource and not infinite for most people

Comment: Well for one, if you use too much, eventually your app will crash or terminate.. For example, creating images with GDI or taking screenshots with GDI, if you forget to free a `DC` and use that function enough times, it will throw `EOUTOFRESOURCE` error.. I had this when I forgot to call `ReleaseDC(NULL, DC)`. Its limited.

Comment: There are several aspects to memory management, some are probably more important than others.  For me, the most important is making sure there are no memory leaks.  Second to that is probably trying to allocate and free various memory allocations symmetrically.  Is there a specific aspect you are interested in?

Comment: No, I am just curious. All the tutorials and books I have tried reading just talk about how memory management is without stating why. Doing that really undermines the importance of things like pointers, references, virtual functions, ect. These responses have already cleared up a lot.

Comment: While this question is quite broad and hard to answer, it is a genuine question, and I do believe that while there is no single correct answer, that an approximate answer is acceptable in this setting, this also happens to apply to a lot of questions here on SO, we're really providing nothing but our best heustics as answers. For the ones who are down voting and flagging this question, how about just editing it for the better?

Comment: Regardless of down votes and flags I got the answers I wanted, but thank you for the advice. And thank you all for your response. A lot of what was said is new information to me, especially regarding good methods of resource management. I don't know how I would go about editing the question since I asked exactly what I wanted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++ are languages which are by most people considered low level (or with low level parts), this allows you to write hardware specific code. And as hardware usually have a lot of preconditions about their input, you'll have to manually manage memory, in terms of memory layout, allocation, padding alike.

This is to be expected when interacting with hardware, and is actually required in order to deal with hardware. However when implementing non hardware specific code, the same utilities and language features still apply. I.e. if you want a piece of dynamic memory, you'll have to explicitly request it, and explicitly release it (the hard part). The way around this, in C++ is to use classes, which helps you handle memory management, by either abstracting the memory management away all together, or by providing garbage collection (usually via reference counting).

The consequence of not cleaning up your garbage, I.e. returning resources to the system, also known as leaking, is that the system will EVENTUALLY run out of resources (as resources are generally limited, although sometimes immense). If your program is small, and has a limited span of executing, this may not be an issue, but nevertheless you should handle your resources, as the hosting environment is actually NOT required to do so, for you, after program termination (although most system will do so, atleast in terms of memory).

Also please notice, that you should have focus on managing resources. Rather than just memory. There are a lot of resources, which are all limited, and hence all needs to be managed. Other resources could be; files, IP sockets, handles, hardware devices, ...

For games in specific, you'll have to expect a high resource usage, in terms of memory and file access, also your game is likely to run, for quite a while (assuming its good), and hence handling resource management becomes critical!

My best piece if advice is keeping away from raw pointers and manual memory management (new/free), and instead using the standard containers (std::vector, alike), value semantics (I.e. pass arguments around by value instead of by pointers.), reference semantics, and if you really have to use pointers, make use of std::unique_ptr, and std::shared_ptr. (This is assuming your writing non hardware code, like a game or a text processor).

Sean Paul did a talk about avoiding pointers at the going native conference in 2013, and it's really worth watching. I can't remember the name of the talk, but it's live on the channel9 webpage for free. The other talks from going native are also recommendable!

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know the answer, but considering that your computer only has a finite amount of memory, it's only natural that applications must manage this memory in a conservative manner.
If, for example, a game poorly manages memory and uses up a large chunk of your 8 gigs of installed ram, other applications that demand a modest amount of memory will essentially start fighting over it. This will usually result in your OS to start swapping memory with other storage mediums and ultimately degrade the performance of your computer until more memory is available.